# Internet browser is showing cached image after applying meta 'cache-control' and 'pragma' too

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser-cache, meta-tags, cache-control

My internet browser: Google Chrome is still showing old cached image when changing the image size and applying filters too. I wrote the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

I also applyed `max-age=0` but internet browser still showing old image. I do not want to do 'clear browsing data' doing manually because all my website visiters do not clear the browsing data for that, I need to tell them individually for seeing the changed image on their browser. Hence, it is complicated.
I had written this code in `head.php` which is included as `<?php include "head.php ?>"` in main document.

With my stylesheets `main.css` and other files as `style.css` were having same problem but after writing as <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css?`version=1.01`> in this way, new styles has been updated but in case of images, save changes on images has not been shown in internet browsers. I also read the `cache-control` documentation in mozilla MDN website. I tried in localhost and in my website too but still showing old one. I did not find the solution to fix this issue. Any solution to write `meta` element to show the fresh image / content in my Google Chrome?